# How to check if a NULL character is in a string when debugging with WinDbg

Tags: c++, winapi, windbg

**For instance:**

```
0:000> ?? testFile //check this variable
char * 0x009c6758
 "e:\TEST\example.FOO"
```

**Question:**

- How can I check for a **NULL-terminated character** in above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clearly there since you are seeing a valid string and not several junk characters afterwards.

db poi(testFile)

Will dump the raw bytes in the string to the console and you'll be able to see a 0 byte at the end.  You can also use the memory window to see the zero byte at the end of the string as well.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm not sure I'm seeing the correct information so I'll dump what I see in my question -- regards

Comment: Corrected my answer, I believe you want to do db poi(testFile).  You're dump the stack address conttaining the pointer (note the bytes, 58, 67, 9c, 00, in little endian are 0x009c6758.